# click on button go to another page and open selected tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 13px; margin-right: 20px;height:auto;">
   <li class="ToActiveP active">
      <a id="PendingBtn" data-toggle="tab">Pending Leaves</a>
   </li>
   @*
   <li>
      <a id="DetailBtn" data-toggle="tab">Leave Detail</a>
   </li>*@
   <li class="ToActive">
      <a id="RecommendedBtn" data-toggle="tab">Recommended Leaves</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a id="SummaryBtn" data-toggle="tab">Leave Detail</a> @*Monthly Summary make this tab leave detail to add filters in this tab and hide the monthly record tab(bcx summary tab was almost duplicate of leave detail tab.)*@
   </li>

   <ul style="list-style:none; float:right;">
      <li><i class="fa fa-square" style="color: #E85108; "></i> <b style="color: #E85108;">Short Leaves</b></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-square" style="color: blue;"></i> <b style="color: blue;">Carry Forward Leaves</b></li>
   </ul>
   @*
   <ul class="unstyled-list">
      <li><i class="fa fa-square" style="color: blue;"></i> <b style="color: blue;">Carry Forwarded</b></li>
   </ul>*@

</ul>
```

Comment: You should say which button you want to click on and remove sections of your code above that are not relevant to your query.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want, but take a look on this link below. A tutotial on how to make a website with tabs (click on tab, loads new part of page without refreshing) using angularjs.

https://thinkster.io/angular-tabs-directive

Comment: my question is when click on button , open another page and not open active tab , open other tab